# Setting Cookies using JavaScript in a local html file

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-browser, local-files

I have the following directory tree:

```
+ folder1
|--- folder2
|------ page1.html
|--- page2.html
```

If I set some cookie in `page1.html` using JavaScript, what is the path used for that cookie?

**Edit:**
Let me explain it better. I'm working with a local file. `page1.html` is being accessed through `/home/user/.../folder1/folder2/page1.html` and not through a client machine using a HTTP Server.

**Just to clarify:**
It seems that some browsers (like Chrome) do not store cookies when using `file:///`, but both Firefox and Internet Explorer do.

Comment: Cookie it independent of the page where it was created, the "path" consists only of the website domain. (Assuming you mean the cookie name as it appears in browser's cookie list)

Comment: See my edit. I don't know why I got a downvote `:(`

Comment: Sorry, thought you didn't check some basic information - disregard.

Comment: Anybody know whether this "feature" has been added in Firefox 57?  I'm trying to debug a problem--my local script used to work in FF until 57, and now it seems to lose the cookie.  That FF has gone over to a no-local-cookies default is one of my hypotheses.  However, it's nearly impossible to web search; all you get is noise about how to enable/disable cookies, or about add-on cookie managers.  This question is the closest I've come.

Comment: Seems no longer available https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470482

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [MDC page for `document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie):

> If not specified, [the `path` argument] defaults to the current path of the current document location.

So in your case, it will be `/folder1/folder2/`.

---

I didn't initially see that you'd specified "local" in the question title -- not sure if this was updated while I was writing my answer. Cookies are not set when browsing using the `file:///` protocol, depending on the browser.

Comment: @Oscar see mine, about 20 pixels from yours!

Comment: yes, that seems the be the thing. IE and Firefox do set cookies using `file:///` but Chrome doesn't do that :) Anyway, I think your answer is correct for IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 23):

Browsers do not store cookies for the `file://` url protocol, it will simply and silently fail to set anything at all. So if this is truly "local" and not on a domain you may have a problem.

Comment: It seems they do. I'm setting a cookie in `page1.html`, then close the browser, open the page again (locally, of course) and then I ask for that cookie and it is still there :?

Comment: @Oscar I think this is a cross-browser thing. Chrome has a slightly different interpretation of the same-origin policy compared to Firefox or Internet Explorer, particularly when it comes to the `file:///` protocol.

Comment: In my case it works in Firefox 77 and does not work in Chrome 83. Both on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 12):

If you're on a mac, you can close Chrome and relaunch it like so:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-file-cookies
```

You'll then be able to set cookies on local files.

Comment: +1: This worked. Used in Terminal. I had to remove the second dash on "--enable-file-cookies" flag, so it should look like: `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome -enable-file-cookies`

Comment: This flag no longer works as the feature has been removed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470482

Answer (score 5):

set --enable-file-cookies for chrome and it should work for you. Also, there are some features that you'll have to set "accept all cookies" also to make work, but if you do, make sure you set back before going back online.

Comment: How set `--enable-file-cookies` it's some where on `chrome://flags` ??

Comment: @Mostafa , I think he means running `chrome --enable-file-cookies` . But it is not working for me on Windows 7 SP2 for Chrome v81.0.4044.138 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for a way, try setting URL parameters instead of cookies

I had downloaded some novels in HTML for offline reading and there was no way to pass previously set font size to next chapters using cookies so what I did is shown below :

1. First add a widow event listener that adds the font size parameter whenever a link(to next ch) is clicked
2. And then window.onload function that takes the parameter value and changes the font size

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="ch-02.html" >Next Chapter</a>
    <p id="content">Hope this helps</p>
    
<script>
var fontSize = 1;
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        location.href = href + "?fontSize=" + fontSize;
        e.preventDefault();
     }
})
window.onload = function(){
  var url = new URL(window.location.href);
  var value = url.searchParams.get("fontSize");
  if(value != null){
    fontSize = parseFloat(value);
    document.getElementById("content").style.fontSize = fontSize + "em";
  }
}
</script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can use Tampermonkey with access to local files ( [How to include Local htm pages in a Tampermonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437050/how-to-include-local-htm-pages-in-a-tampermonkey-script) )
By that way you will use Tampermonkey's storage, and will be able to set and get your data  by functions GM_getValue(data) and GM_setValue(data). I used that for my local HTML page, which i used as customizable alternative to Windows Explorer