# Javascript cookie not being set

Tags: javascript, cookies

If I am not mistaken, javascript cookies should be set by the code

```
document.cookie = "name=content;expires=100000;path=/"
```

However, this is not setting cookies, `document.cookie` remains blank. What am I doing incorrectly?
[image]

My webpage is using jQuery, ajax, and bootstrap scripts.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: tested works for me

Comment: Similarly works for me. Can you post more of your sources?

Comment: @JoshuaNelson Sources and screenshot added to body

Comment: Is your URL starting with `file://`?

Comment: @PredatorIWD It is

Comment: I assumed so, you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136034/6586663) answer.

Comment: As @PredatorIWD suggested, what you need is to run your code on a web server. Cookies do not function for local files. You have run it as `http://localhost` or a variant of it.