# My cookie for javascript is not working for my login page prototype

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

The cookie is not working, and I do not see any errors in the console. Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to fix it? I've been working on it for days.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQxYo.jpg)

I tried to get some help at w3schools and here, and nothing worked. I expect the code to save my username (not working on password or anything yet) once I fill out my username form and click 'submit'. The username should come up in the console as '<login> cookieconfirm: username = *the username*'. Thank you.

Javascript (login.js)

```
// cookie manager
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + exdays + ";path=/";
    console.log('<cookie> added "' + cname + '=' + cvalue + ';' + expires + ';path=/' + '"')
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + '=';
    let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
// login code
// login details
function loginCheck() {
    if (getCookie('username') == '') {
        alert('You are not logged in.');
        console.log('<login> not logged in.');
    } else {
        console.log('<login> username = ' + getCookie('username'));
    }
}
// login detail storage
function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    console.log('<login> login request recieved.');
    console.log('<login> username is : ' + username)
    setCookie('username', username, 7);
    console.log('<login> cookieconfirm: username = ' + getCookie('username'));
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Lorem Ipsum | Login</title>
    <script src="../java/head.js"></script>
    <script src="../java/favicon.js"></script>
    <script src="../java/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loginCheck()">
    <a href="../index.html"><img id="orangeblob" src="../images/icon.png"></a>
    <h1 class="headertext">
        LOGIN
    </h1>
    <hr class="line">
    <form>
        <label for="username"><p id="big">USERNAME:</p></label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
        <label for="password"><p id="big">PASSWORD:</p></label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="login()">
    </form>
    <script src="../java/copyrights.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this error? It seems to work fine on Firefox and Chrome.

The only issue seems to be the use of `exdays` instead of `';' + expires` when you set the cookie, but even with this problem it works on my computer.

*(I tried adding this as a comment, but cannot due to restrictions as a new user.)*

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it's because of this Chrome feature (bug??) = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385641/javascript-code-for-cookie-not-working-in-chrome