# How to fix undefined cookie value in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, undefined, jquery-cookie

I am using a [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), to set and store a cookie of a modal, so it will only show once when the user visits a website. I tested the modal and it worked as so in the latest versions of Firefox, IE, and Microsoft Edge, however, Google Chrome doesn't work and repeatedly brings up the modal upon every page refresh. I created an alert to read the value of the said cookie with:

`alert($.cookie("modal_shown")); // read available cookie`

I debugged it in the console and noticed the above code returns as follows:

Firefox: `1`
Internet Explorer: `yes`
Microsoft Edge: `yes`
Google Chrome: `undefined`
Opera: `undefined`

With that being said, using the browser console, I'm trying to figure out why the last two browsers gives me a value of `undefined` whereas the others are working properly? Any solutions to resolving this?

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   
        <h2>Notice!</h2>
        <div class="control_toggle_icon"></div>
        <p style="text-align:left; margin: 0 0 12px;">Toggle this menu icon to show/hide the menu bar and view the images in full screen.</p>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="modal_btn shortcode_button btn_small btn_type1">Okay, Got it!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The modal is basically the same as I'm using from a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/) snippet.**

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    // only show modal once and hide it until expired
    if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) 
    {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
        // show modal
        $(".modalDialog").css({opacity : "1", pointerEvents : "auto"});
    }

    // destroy modal upon click
    $(".modal_btn").click(function(){
        $(".modalDialog").css({opacity : "0", pointerEvents : "none"});
    });
    alert($.cookie("modal_shown")); // read available cookie
});
</script>
```

**UPDATED TEST CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    console.log(cookieVal); // undefined
    var cookieVal = $.cookie("modal_shown") || "no";
    console.log(cookieVal); // "no", "1" for firefox, "yes" for ie, me

    // only show modal once and hide it until expired
    if (cookieVal !== "yes")
    {
        console.log(cookieVal); // "no", "1" for firefox, "yes" for ie, me
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 365, path: '/' }); // here it doesn't change the value to yes until next line
        cookieVal= "yes"; // force value to become yes from no
        // show modal
        $(".modalDialog").css({opacity : "1", pointerEvents : "auto"});
        console.log(cookieVal); // "yes"
    }

    // destroy modal upon click
    $(".modal_btn").click(function(){
        $(".modalDialog").css({opacity : "0", pointerEvents : "none"});
        console.log(cookieVal); // "yes"
    });
});
</script>
```

**Resolution: Had to upload the code to a local or online server for the jquery cookie to fully work as expected. It now worked in all the modern browser versions. The modal will show up once and never again (or until the set expiration date, in this case, 365 days) on page refresh or closing/reopening the browser.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cookie value does not exist, then `$.cookie()` will return `undefined`.  So, you can either test for that specific value or you can assign a default value.

If you want to assign a default value and your expected values are `"no"`, `"yes"` or `undefined`, then you can do something like this:

```
var cookieVal = $.cookie("modal_shown") || "no";
```

Which could be incorporated like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    // only show modal once and hide it until expired
    var cookieVal = $.cookie("modal_shown") || "no";
    console.log(cookieVal);      // log cookieVal
    if (cookieVal !== "yes") {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
        // show modal
        $(".modalDialog").css({opacity : "1", pointerEvents : "auto"});
    }

    // destroy modal upon click
    $(".modal_btn").click(function() {
        $(".modalDialog").css({opacity : "0", pointerEvents : "none"});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, I remember you by your name! So, in my code I would do like so: `if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null || $.cookie('modal_shown') == undefined) {...}`? I tried this and still remains undefined.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight - Your `if` statement did not effect your `alert()` at all.  That's why nothing changed.  I added a code suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I see what you did there. I updated my code above and tried to play around with getting it right, but the "yes" value passed from the cookie doesn't get changed and I added a condition to force the value to change if it isn't a "yes" value, but the modal keeps coming up and now for all the browsers it's doing that. It seems the plugin isn't rendering correctly or I'm doing something wrong I don't see.

Comment: Resolution: I uploaded it to a local server and see if it registered, and it did worked! I suppose working with cookies offline doesn't work, but uploading to a local server did. That's interesting. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight - browsers each have different rules for when they will store cookies when using `file://` URLs - behavior is not standard.  Chrome requires special configuration before it will do so.  Other browsers will do it by default.  I guess it's one of those things where we didn't know you were using `file://` URLs.  Anyway, glad you got it figured out.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232331/setting-cookies-using-javascript-in-a-local-html-file