# Creating cookies on file:/// url - evidence it is being created but not showing in document.cookie or cookie list in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, file, cookies

I have some code that creates cookies. It creates two different user groups, checks for what group the users cookie is and does something based on it.

**The code is being developed on a local machine so it is accessed through a file:/// URL**

It looks like this:

```
function cookieCreation() {
                var groupId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
                var expDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+60*60*1000*24).toGMTString()
                document.cookie = "userGroup_" + groupId + ";" + "expires=" + expDate +";path=/";
            }

            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                        var c = ca[i];
                            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                                c = c.substring(1);
                            }
                        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                        }
                    }
                return "";
            }

            function cookieBasedPush() {
                cookieCreation();
                var currentCookie = getCookie("userGroup_1");

                if (currentCookie == null) {
                    console.log("User Group 2");
                } else {
                    console.log("User Group 1");
                }
            }

            window.onload = cookieBasedPush;
```

A cookie *looks like* it is being created because I can see "User Group 1" is being console logged. However, when I run document.cookie, I get nothing.

I searched and found [Setting Cookies using JavaScript in a local html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232331/setting-cookies-using-javascript-in-a-local-html-file) and based on this answer, suggests that cookies can't be created in a file:/// URL.

That is what confuses me and doesn't make any sense - If that is the case, then why am I getting a successful console.log of the user group 1 cookie creation? Why is document.cookie blank when run in console? Is my logic not right in code?

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are *strictly* a HTTP mechanism as per [RFC 2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt).

See this link, [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535), for the chrome "bug" report of this.

<strike>You can, however, run chrome with the flag `--enable-file-cookies` to allow file:/// cookies</strike>

To run chrome with experimental / developer flags have a look [here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags) for instructions

It appears that the `--enable-file-cookies` flag has been removed from all platforms that chrome runs on except Android.
You can read more about it [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470482) and [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/1034703003).

With this, it appears that there is no way to store cookies under a `file:///` URL structure, The best way to go around this would be to run a small server locally when developing. Here's a good list of scripts that can run a local HTTP server from the command line. [link](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)

Comment: Ok - so keeping that in mind, why would this code consolelog "User Group 1" if cookies are disabled on `file:///`? what is my logic flaw?

Comment: You are still getting the log `"User Group 1"` because you're checking if the returned value in the function `getCookie()` (That is an empty string) is equal to `null`, For a start, You don't need to have a `return` to the end of a function, secondly, `null` is NOT equal to `""`. Have a look here to learn about datatypes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures | Also, when checking if something is "equal" to something, make sure to use type-safe equality operators, `===` and `!==` instead of their regular counterparts `==` and `!=`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting it so I apologize in advance. So that means a cookie is being generated then, right? Because if it was null it would return User Group 2 (which I'm realizing is a flaw but that I'll try to work out later) I made changes suggested so changed checking for null to check for `""` in the `cookieBasedPush()` function, deleted retrun and am using the type-safe operator, so `===` but I still get User Group 1.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I've updated it to correct my previous mistake with regards to running chrome with said flag.

Comment: There should be no cookies then and it should always be null. It can't be `null` if I'm getting User Group 1, correct?

Comment: At this point, the question is more as to why this code isn't working for you, I think that there is no point debugging the script in its current state, 
 You need to do some reading up in terms of cookies, While this (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) W3 Schools article is good, simply copying code isn't going to help you learn, The code that you copied is not very applicable for any real use, If you outline your needs and what you want to use this script for you can email me here; https://voidtyphoon.co.uk/email/stackoverflow and I'll be more than happy to help you there :)

Comment: Alright I may send you a note later - it's not that I don't know about cookies or anything. I'll try to pick at this later.

Comment: Sure thing, The code seems like it might be confusing you was my only concern, a different approach might be better as it won't be so tightly packed together in functions as this is :)