# Local html and js files opened via file:/// in browser: is it possible to use cookies in JS?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am making a .html file that is meant to be open locally, therefore not accessed via http:// but via file:///

Firefox rejects the cookie I try to create in javascript, saying there is already a cookie HTTP-Only:
`document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT;path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=Strict;";`

Is there a way to use cookies for a local page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are not set for local pages via file:///. See here for more information: [Setting Cookies using JavaScript in a local html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232331/setting-cookies-using-javascript-in-a-local-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not store cookies for the file:// url protocol, although it may depend on the browser anyway

e.g launching chrome with **--enable-file-cookies**